# How to make Wrap to not minimise height (reduce number of rows) as much as possible

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to build a "semi-responsive" widget. It has a fixed number of relatively large children that always fit on the screen horizontally (A, B and C) and a variable list of small children that not always fit horizontally together with A, B, and C. My idea is to have the widget look like the first picture when the screen is wide, and as a second when the screen is more narrow, and as a third when there's no space for smaller widgets at all. What I'm getting is the third only. As if `Wrap` always tries to put as many children horizontally as possible. I want it to minimize width instead.
My pseudocode:

```dart
Card(
  child: Wrap(
    children: [
      Row(children: [A(), B(), C()]),
      Wrap(children: [1(), 2(), 3(), 4(), 5()]),
    ]
  ),
);
```

Any idea how to "squeeze" `Wrap` vertically? Using standard layout widgets if possible.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can archive that using the alignment property in the Wrap widget.

```
Card( 
   child: Wrap( 
      alignment: WrapAlignment.end, 
      children: [ 
            Row(children: [A(), B(), C()]),
            1(), 2(), 3(), 4(), 5(), 
       ],),
 );
```

check it out in dartpad [gist](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/89f76611acdea87c4f54448944216634)

Comment: Your solution doesn't really use two child `Wrap`s as wraps. They act like `Row`s, they never wrap. The only break points are between these two wraps. And that's exactly the behavior I'm trying to overcome.

Comment: This will work as you want 

`Card(`
  `child: Wrap(`
    `alignment: WrapAlignment.end,`
    `children: [`
      `Row(children: [A(), B(), C()]),`
      `1(), 2(), 3(), 4(), 5(),`
    `]`
  ),
);`

Comment: Like this? https://gist.github.com/kika/c1153567346945694bb93f31b582a1fd ? It has exactly the problem I'm describing, "numeric" widgets never wrap one by one, they jump onto the next line of widgets together.

Comment: No. Like this. [gist](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/89f76611acdea87c4f54448944216634)